# Glass not appearing transparent

Tags: materials, lighting, glass

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to make a glass model. As you can see below it's not see through though.

[image: Dysfunctional Glass]

This is my material config:

[image]

And based on my research so far I've tried flipping and recalculating the normals which has had no effect. I also tried inserting the Glass BSDF which also was not transparent which makes me think there's something else not right with the normals.

Comment: if you are in Eevee you need to go into Materials > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Eevee render engine. By default, Eevee isn't set up to show up reflections and refractions. And materials have refractions disabled by default. These have to be enabled in the render settings first.

First, let's enable refractions for the material you need. In the `Properties Editor`, `Material` tab, scroll down to the `Options` panel and check `Screen Space Refraction`.

[image: material settings]

This alone just lets  Eevee know that this material has refraction to be rendered, you yet have to let Eevee render them:

In the `Properties Editor`, go to the `render settings` tab, you should find a `Screenspace Reflexion` panel with an unchecked checkbox. Check it, open the panel, and check `refraction` as well. Now Eevee should be able to render reflections and refractions.

[image: eevee settings]

Comment: That is amazing that you can remember all that without access to Blender! That fixes it exactly, thanks a lot!